Unexpected margin inside Flutter Column widget
i'm writing a code inside a column, but i have an unexpecting size. I think it's a margin, but i don't know where it was .. Does someones had this thing ?
Column(
      children: [
        Text("test"),
        // Here some margin, why ?
        Container(
          height: 200,
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: answers.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Text(answers[index]);
            }
          ),
        )
      ],
    );


I tried to put SizedBox instead of my Container but not work. Maybe it's normal ?
I tried to remove SizedBox or Container, to get only my ListView, but this blank is always here.
Here is Flutter Inspector :
The 20 height with green border is the Text "test" before the List

Thanks !

try https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/inspector, the docs say: '''The inspector helps you visualize and explore Flutter widget trees, and can be used for the following:
*** understanding existing layouts
*** diagnosing layout issues'''

I added the inspector image, thanks for your answer

i mean you will see your widgets on the right side ("Layout Explorer" tab), like here: https://docs.flutter.dev/assets/images/docs/tools/devtools/inspector_screenshot.png - this will help you to identify where the gap comes from

I see, thanks ! i tried but nothing special i guess .. Updated my image

It might the default padding of ListView. You could try
ListView.builder(
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Text("answers[$index]");
  }),
)


Thanks you ! I didn't know there was a default padding on ListView !
